# Create excel using laravel command

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

We are running a command where the data is fetched. And we want to create the excel with charts in it which nee to be sent as attachment. When executing the command nothing happened. Can anyone please help me.

```
    public function handle()
    {
        try{
            Excel::download(new emailTriggerExport,'exportTrigger.xlsx');
        }catch(Exception $e){
            dd($e);
            Log::error('EmailReportTrigger-command () : '.$e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: The command is executed in cli mode, no Response Download can be Created.
You can store the Excel in file system and attach to Mail or some way getting the url and download.

Comment: as u can see i have used download which is expeted to download the file named emailtrigger.xlsx but nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

simply add return

```
    public function handle()
    {
        try{
            return Excel::download(new emailTriggerExport,'exportTrigger.xlsx');
        }catch(Exception $e){
            dd($e);
            Log::error('EmailReportTrigger-command () : '.$e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        
    }
```

Here's [a link](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/)!

Comment: it retturns   Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse could not be converted to int